# R create new column where the value depends on the matching of two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have troubles putting my question into words (hence the weird title) but :

I want to create a new column Earnings, that will take the value of the `Price` of the `Date` that matches the `Last trading day`. Like this :

For the first row, the last trading day is `2014-02-17`, so I check in the Date column, and in the 5th row, the Date is equal to `2014-02-17`. So I take the price of the 5th row which is 235 and assign it to all rows that have `2014-02-17` as the `Last trading day`.

```
   Price     Date       `Last trading day`           Earnings
  <dbl>     <date>       <date>                        <dbl>
    224. 2013-01-02   2014-02-17                      235
    224. 2013-01-02   2014-02-17                      235
    224. 2013-01-02   2014-02-17                      235
    224. 2013-01-02   2014-04-19                      260
    235. 2014-02-17   2014-04-19                      260
    260. 2014-04-19   2014-06-17                      253
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
   library(dplyr)
   library(plyr)
   df<-data %>%
   group_by(`Last trading day`) %>%
   mutate(Earnings = if_else(data$Date==data$`Last trading day`, Price, NA_real_))
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipes. How do you get `Earnings` value for first row as 235?

Comment: It is the price of the date that is equal to the last trading day. @RonakShah

Comment: I don't get it `2013-01-02` is not the last trading day still how does it get 235?

Comment: @RonakShah For the first row, the last trading day is `2014-02-17`, so I check in the Date column, and in the 5th row, the Date is equal to `2014-02-17`. So I take the price of the 5th row which is 235 and assign it to all rows that have `2014-02-17` as the `Last trading day`.

Comment: The last trading day  `2014-06-17 ` is not present in `Date` anywhere . How does it get 253?

Comment: @RonakShah it's just the head of the data, but it is present below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` :

```
df$Earnings <- df$Price[match(df$Last_trading_day, df$Date)]
```

Using it in `dplyr` pipe :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Earnings = Price[match(Last_trading_day, Date)])
```

---

Another option is to join dataframe with itself.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% left_join(df, by = c('Last_trading_day' = 'Date'))
```

I renamed the spaces in column name of `Last Trading day` with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the `data$` as it will take the whole column by breaking the group attribute instead of the values within each group

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(`Last trading day`) %>%
   mutate(Earnings = if_else(Date== `Last trading day`, Price, NA_real_))
```

Or another option is `case_when`

```
data %>%
   group_by(`Last trading day`) %>%
   mutate(Earnings = case_when(Date== `Last trading day` ~ Price))
```

---

Also, as we are comparing elementwise, we don't need any `group_by`

```
data %>%      
   mutate(Earnings = if_else(Date== `Last trading day`, Price, NA_real_))
```

Or with `case_when` remove the `group_by`

---

The above solutions were based on the code OP showed.  If we need to do a replacement based on the two columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df, on = .(Last_trading_day =  Date)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think that this code compares within a row, meaning that it only works if the  `Last trading day` is equal to `Date` on the same row. What I want it to do is compare with all rows, like in the example.

Comment: @Narjems this is based on your code and how it should be corrected

Comment: @Narjems It's okay, but based on the input on your dataset, I was trying to help